# Retrieve retroactive list of Twitter follower IDs in R

Tags: r, twitter, web-scraping

I'm trying to use R to retroactively retrieve the full list of Donald Trump's followers from April 19, 2016.  As of now, my code looks like this:

```
library(httr)
library(twitteR)
library(base64enc)
library(igraph)
library(maps)
library(geosphere)
library(RColorBrewer)
consumerKey <- "xxxxxxxxxx"
consumerSecret <- "xxxxxxxxxx"
accessToken <- "xxxxxxxxxx"
accessSecret <- "xxxxxxxxxx"
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key=consumerKey, consumer_secret=consumerSecret, access_token=accessToken, access_secret=accessSecret)
me <- getUser("realdonaldtrump")
followers <- me$getFollowers()
followerIDs <- me$getFollowerIDs()
```

(I've replaced my consumer key/secret and access token/secret with x's, since you're not supposed to share those codes.)

This code gets stuck when it hits the second to last line, because Donald Trump has over 9 million followers. So, what I'm unclear on is: 1) how to retrieve the full list of followers, and 2) how to retroactively retrieve the list from April 19th of this year.

Comment: It looks like you're doing it correctly, but you're searching for the wrong Donald Trump. You should be searching for "realDonaldTrump", assuming you want the presidential candidate. I don't think you'll be able to do what you want using the free API - you'll hit the rate limit trying to get all of his followers (he has over 9 million), and it doesn't look like you have the option to pull from a particular date.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, @Tchotchke! I've edited the question according to your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to collect retrospective data on a Twitter user's followers. In order to collect the full follower list, you will need to avoid getting rate limited by Twitter. The TwitteR package has a function that will allow you to see how much data you may collect within a certain time frame. Then, you can use Sys.sleep to avoid being rate limited.